# NestJS - proper way to copy static (non-imported) files to dist folder

Tags: google-cloud-platform, static, google-cloud-storage, gcloud, nestjs

I'm building an app that uses google cloud apis (e.g. Google Cloud Storage). In order to authenticate the app with the api I need to pass the path of the `keyfile.json` file that contains auth credentials to the GCloud Api initialization script.
I.e.

```
const storage = new Storage({
      keyFilename: path.join(__dirname, '../../keyfile.json'),
});
```

I put the `keyfile.json` into the NestJS `src` folder but when I build the app, the file is not copied to `dist`.

What would be recommended way to handle static files copying to dist in NestJS?

Comment: Any reason to not have the file in `root/static` or something similar? That way for bot h `src` and `dist` the path is the same?

Comment: Oh... right. Forgot about static folder completely. Thanks. I think this will do for now

Comment: Alternatively, have you ruled-out using the app's (runtime's) service account and application default credentials? This saves distributing keys alongside your sources.

Comment: @DazWilkin, not sure I understand. Could you explain your idea a bit more? I do think that the way I've done it now is not really the approach to go

Comment: Each compute runtime on GCP runs code as a service account. Your code can (very easily) authenticate as this account using App Default Credentials. Then, as long as that account has the appropriate IAM permissions, your code will be authorized to make the method calls. See this link: https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production In all of these cases, if your code is running under (App|Compute|Kubernetes|Functions), it will automagically be authenticated by a service account.

Answer (score 18):

Just declare your directory in the assets array of `nest-cli.json`:

```
{
    "collection": "@nestjs/schematics",
    "sourceRoot": "src",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "assets": [
            "resources/*"
        ]
    }
}
```

Source: https://docs.nestjs.com/cli/monorepo#assets

Comment: I'm not sure this only applies to monorepo projects, not finding anything in the documentation that suggests this to be the case

Comment: @nomadoda it's under /cli/monorepo#assets and at the time there was a note specifying this. If you managed to make it work I can update to remove the monorepo mention ?

Comment: Yes, it's working well for me in a standard setup

Comment: @nomadoda updated my answer ! thanks consider upvoting question+answer if it helped

Answer (score 0):

Just to make things clear here and to add an important point:

- when you create and deploy your app engine, the app engine default
  service account will be created and used as the identity of the App
  Engine service.
- The App Engine default service account is associated with your Google
  Cloud project and executes tasks on behalf of your apps running in
  App Engine.
- By default, the App Engine default service account has the Editor
  role in the project.
- Also, Your App Engine app uses the credentials of the App Engine
  service account by default.
- And that's how it feels like **magically** your app is making calls to Google Cloud 
  API without authentication settings

[You can find this info here.](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/service-account)